# How to use server database in TestContext in spring instead of the in memory h2 database?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to use a server database in my `TestConfiguration`. I have defined a Postgresql database in my `application.properties`, which should be used by the application, however the `TestContext` is using an embedded h2 database. 
The `application.properties` has the following content:

[image]

H2 is defined as a dependency in the `pom.xml file`, when I remove and try to build without I get an error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:180)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:121)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I added the error to the question.

Comment: Do you have the postgre driver on the classpath?

Comment: The postgresql is defined in the pom.

Comment: You have to tell to your `TestContext` to use the database details defined on your `application.properties`.  I'm guessing that it cannot find the property file when you're building it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the scope that I have defined in the pom for postgresql.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I set the scope to provided everything works fine.